# The subscriptions getting called multiple times, when navigated to different page and coming back again in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, ngoninit

I have a function A and B.
I want both these functions to run at the initial of the component load, on ngOnInit, but B should run only after the completion of A. Coz for B to run, i will need values from A. For this, I kept B inside A. A has observables. Hence the subscriptions is getting called two times, navigate to different page and come back again, its getting called 3 times and so on.
I have two different objects, say **data:any** and **array1** that needs to be filled up in A's code.

Example A code:

```
ngOnInit(){
    A();
}

A(){
    this.service1.getData().subscribe((resp)=>
        if(resp){
            //some logic
            this.service2.dataFor.pipe(skipWhile((val)=>val ===null )).subscribe((response)=>{
            //some logic to fill up data and array1 from the subscribed data
            })
        }
    )
}


B(){
    if(this.data && Object.keys(this.data).length>0){
        this.service3.getValidity(this.data.data).subscribe((resp)=>{
        if(resp){
            //some code
            console.log("from B if");

        }
        
        else if(this.array1.length===0){
            this.service3.getValidity('').subscribe((res)=>{
                //some logic
                console.log("from B else");
            })
        }
        })
    }
}
```

For now what I am doing is calling B() inside A(), something like:

```
A(){

    this.service1.getData().subscribe((resp)=>
        if(resp){
            //some logic
            this.service2.dataFor.pipe(skipWhile((val)=>val ===null )).subscribe((response)=>{
            //some logic to fill up data and array1 from the subscribed data
            
            console.log("from A ");
            B();
            //after data and array1 has data
            })
        }
    )
}
```

What this does is calls subscriptions multiple times and At first displays **from B if** two times, if I navigate to another page and come back to this page again, it displays 3 times, similarly 4,5,6... times.

I thought not unsubscribing the subscriptions may have caused this, so on

```
ngOnDestroy(){
     //unsubscribed all the subscriptions
}
```

full code for reference:

```
A(){
    this.subscription1=this.service1.getData().subscribe((resp)=>
        if(resp){
            //some logic
            this.subscription2=this.service2.dataFor.pipe(skipWhile((val)=>val ===null )).subscribe((response)=>{
            //some logic to fill up data and array1 from the subscribed data
            
            B();
            //after data and array1 has data
            })
        }
    )
}


B(){
    if(this.data && Object.keys(this.data).length>0){
        this.subscription3=this.service3.getValidity(this.data.data).subscribe((resp)=>{
        if(resp){
            //some code
        }
        
        else if(this.array1.length===0){
            this.service3.getValidity('').subscribe((res)=>{
                //some logic
            })
        }
        })
    }
}


ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscription1 && !this.subscription1.closed) {
      this.subscription1.unsubscribe();
    }
    if (this.subscription2 && !this.subscription2.closed) {
      this.subscription2.unsubscribe();
    }
    if (this.subscription3 && !this.subscription3.closed) {
      this.subscription3.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

This didnt work either.

I think the nested function calls, B() inside A() is causing this.

I want A() to complete storing the values in **data** and **array1** and then only B() should run.

How do I achieve this in an efficient way? and without subscriptions being called multiple times.

Comment: > 'I thought not unsubscribing the subscriptions may have caused this, so on',  

can you please append the code reference for unsubscribe too?  
I count 4 subscriptions, did you unsubscribe to all the 4? (2 (top level subscribes)at the least).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subscribing, you could could use `firstValueFrom` (https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom) which is returning a Promise from a Observable.
Then you can simply await the promise, which resolves only once.

```
import { firstValueFrom, map } from 'rxjs';

async ngOnInit() {
    const response = await firstValueFrom(A());
    B(response);
}
A() {
    return this.service1.getData().pipe(
        map((resp) => {
            return; //do something with the response
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: Module '"rxjs"' has no exported member 'firstValueFrom'. i get this

Comment: Do you have rxjs in your dependencies?
If so, firstValueFrom was added in the latest version.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use ``await A().toPromise()``which was the previous way to do it.

Comment: I probably dont have the latest and its a corporate code, so i cant add a newer version for now, even for map its showing up the same, what would i have to change in function A() for that

Comment: You can use ``await  this.service2.dataFor.pipe(skipWhile((val)=>val ===null )).toPromise()``
which will run the code synchronous afterwards.
Just make sure to write `async` in front of your function declarations as well.